# run download link and unzip to a folder in python with a url that stores a variable

Tags: python, variables, input, hyperlink, unzip

How could a script in python be made that, through a value entered by the user through the console in an input, is replaced in a specific url of a repository to be able to download a .zip and when it is downloaded automatically, a folder is created where it is entered and would unpack, for example:

Given two random github urls:

https://github.com/exercism/python/archive/refs/heads/bobahop-patch-1.zip

https://github.com/exercism/python/archive/refs/heads/bobahop-patch-2.zip

The user could enter "patch-1" or "patch-2" by console and this value would be replaced in the url and in turn the link would be executed and the .zip it contains would be downloaded to the repository. Simultaneously, a folder with any name would be created (the value entered by the user in the console, for example) and the downloaded .zip would be moved to that folder and once there it would be decompressed.

Comment: python has: modules like `urllib` or `requests` to get something from web page, and module `zipfile` to compress/uncompress .zip file, and `os.makedir()` to create folder. It has also `os.rename()` to move to folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has

- standard module `urllib` to get/download data from web page `urllib.request.urlretrieve()`
- standard moduel `os` to create folder `os.makedirs()` and move/rename file `os.rename()`
- standard module `zipfile` to compress/uncompress `.zip` file

```
import os
import urllib.request
import zipfile

#user_input = input("What to download: ")
user_input = 'patch-1'

pattern = 'https://github.com/exercism/python/archive/refs/heads/bobahop-{}.zip'
url = pattern.format(user_input)

filename = f"{user_input}.zip"

print('From:', url)
print('  To:', filename)

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)

# ---

destination_folder = user_input
print('Create folder:', destination_folder)

os.makedirs(destination_folder, exist_ok=True)

# ---

print('Uncompress')

zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(filename)
zip_file.extractall(destination_folder)

# ---

print("Move .zip to folder")

old_name = filename
new_name = os.path.join(destination_folder, filename)
os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your incredible help furas! It is exactly what I was trying to get done and I was not able to do it... I am going to study the code you have given me well in order to learn the whole process well and be able to do it by myself without needing help

Thank you  :)